# Destory function issue GET request on firefox 20

Tags: firefox

I have a strange bug where I issue a standard destroy function on a standard backbone Model but GET request is received on the server side instead of DELETE:

The request code

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
idAttribute: "id",
url: "/private/1.1/user/"
})



user = new User({"id":"ilya+1@test.com"})

user.destroy()
```

I see it in firebug as a proper DELETE request

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/private/1.1/user/
```

But when I fire up wireshark the actual request sent is GET rather than DELETE on firefox 20(on linux), on chrome this works as expected

Comment: It's not a Backbone problem. There's nothing in the library that would do that.

Comment: Yeah, your right, I though about it after I wrote it. Still strange though

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a noscript bug triggered by a css file, go figure...

One conclusion, if something strange goes on in net, try to disable noscript.